# Compute hash of class code at runtime (C#)?

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to compute the hash of a class at runtime in C# (presumably through reflection)? To be clear, I don't want to compute the hashcode of an instance of said class, I want to compute the hash of the class code itself (if a function in the class changes, I'd expect a different hash code to be computed). Ideally this would only be sensitive to changes in the object code (and not just a hash of the string representation of the code itself).

Thanks in advance for your help,

-- Breck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have the `Type` you can use `GetMethod` to get an instance of `MethodInfo`, which in turn has a [`GetMethodBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx) that returns the IL for said method. You can then hash that.

I am curious. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: The reason I want to do this is that in my case I have a function, f, of considerable time complexity. The problem is that I'm experimenting  with the values f should be returning, so f changes frequently. If a particular version of f, fi, has already run for an input, x, I want to cache the result, fi(x) so that if fi runs again, it can just use the memoized value.

Comment: In my case the reason is that I save snapshots (a memoized value) for a POCO class with internal methods. If some internal method of the class is modified, I need to invalidate that snapshot. I will try this, thanks

Comment: In my case, it is to ensure some results saved in DB are still valid using the "version" of the class. For this purpose, I created a class which I just added as solution to this question.

Comment: This has great utility in testing as well -- I have a test that sets up some static data and saves it to a file on the disc so that I can reuse it for every test instance. That said, If I change the function definition I want it to rebuild a new instance of the cache file using the new definition.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I wanted to share my `HashClassCalculator` that gives an hash of the code of all methods and properties. So, if anything change in those, the hash will change.

```
internal static class HashClassCalculator
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, string> hashes = new ();
    private static object lockingObject = new ();

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate an hash of the code for a specific type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">Type to hash the code</param>
    /// <returns>MD5 hash of the class code</returns>
    /// <remarks>Thread protected + Cached for faster access</remarks>
    public static string CalculateHash(Type type)
    {
        if (hashes.ContainsKey(type)) return hashes[type]; // Fast return

        var currentHash = "";
        lock (lockingObject)
        {
            if (hashes.ContainsKey(type)) return hashes[type]; // Fast return

            var allFlag = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static;
            var hasher = MD5.Create();

            // Get all properties hashes
            var props = type.GetProperties(allFlag);
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var hashBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(prop.GetMethod.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray());
                currentHash += Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes); // Concatenate all the hashes
            }

            // Get all methods hashes
            var methods = type.GetMethods(allFlag);
            foreach (var method in methods)
            {
                if (method.DeclaringType != type) continue;

                var hashBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray());
                currentHash += Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes); // Concatenate all the hashes
            }

            // Hashing all hashes into one smaller
            var hashOfHashes = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(currentHash));
            currentHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashOfHashes);

            // Add to cache
            hashes.Add(type, currentHash);
        }

        return currentHash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use reflection. You can try `System.Type.GetHashCode()`. I'm not sure how it works, if not optimal, than you can always use `type.FullName.GetHashCode()`

Comment: Type.GetHashCode() seems to change its value between recompiles. type.FullName.GetHashCode() wouldnt' change hashes for when a method changes.

Comment: System.Type.GetHashCode will work just fine, it will change if a method name changes or a parameter name / type changes, etc., type.FullName.GetHashCode will not work as the type name could stay the same but a method might change.

Comment: @Jeff: class Program { static void Main() { Console.Write(typeof(Program).GetHashCode(); } } changes its output between compiles.

Comment: @Jimmy You're right, I should have run my test twice with the same exact class, sorry...