# How can I get a hash of the body of a method in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to generate a hash of a method body or entire class in order to compare it to a previous hash and therefore detect changes at run-time.

I've seen reference to this being achieved in Mono using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/).

Is it possible to do this in Microsoft.NET? If so how?

Or what other approaches have you used?

**Background**

I'd like to create projections of my entities into a read-only, denormalised database - a kind of local cache if you like.

The transformation algorithm that does this will be pinged whenever a change has occurred to the entities.  It will then take the entity in question and generate the projection.  However, on start up or as part of the deployment, I'd like to check if the transformation algorithm has changed and if so delete and regenerate the table and then repopulate it using all the entities in the main store.

I've seen this approach suggested in Event Source/CQRS blogs but feel free to comment if you have alternative/better approaches to this requirement.

**Incomplete Solution based on Jon Skeet's Answer**

The following LinqPad C# Program is an attempt at implementing this:

```
void Main()
{
    GetMethodHash(this.GetType(), "DoOriginal").Dump();
    GetMethodHash(this.GetType(), "DoSame").Dump();
    GetMethodHash(this.GetType(), "DoWithConstChange").Dump();
    GetMethodHash(this.GetType(), "DoWithCodeChange").Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

private string DoOriginal(int data)
{
    return string.Format("data = {0}", data);
}

private string DoSame(int data)
{
    return string.Format("data = {0}", data);
}

private string DoWithConstChange(int data)
{
    return string.Format("data : {0}", data);
}

private string DoWithCodeChange(int data)
{
    return string.Format("data = {0} {1}", data, 999);
}

private string GetMethodHash(Type type, string methodName)
{
    var method = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );
    var body = method.GetMethodBody();
    var il = body.GetILAsByteArray();

    using (var sha256 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create())
    {
        byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(il);
        string hashBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", methodName.PadRight(20), hashBase64);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
DoOriginal          +PyMqwv5PVz7/7EnNL9A676XNw/g8x2KfEUa63wD9oU=
DoSame              +PyMqwv5PVz7/7EnNL9A676XNw/g8x2KfEUa63wD9oU=
DoWithConstChange   VZX2CkxwUHzJVt8Tn73jmL1I5dKYUFKyD9bPwPsItVk=
DoWithCodeChange    9kZkq0fDHUXqxOmclwso/r2pQLDyNVwTtkIppSkcdQg=
```

My first investigation with this appeared to produce the same hash between DoOriginal and DoWithConstChange ... but that was before lunch and now it looks okay.  So either something odd was going on or I needed the break - I vote the latter.

Next up would be to add in referenced code and structures.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can define *version* attribute for a method, which you change manually when doing a change to a method body itself.

Comment: Another thought would be to try to use [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) as a way of deciding if the code has changed in such a way as to affect the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute hash of class code at runtime (C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480472/compute-hash-of-class-code-at-runtime-c)

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`MethodInfo.GetMethodBody()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx) to get a [`MethodBody`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.aspx), then create a hash based on whatever you like (e.g. the [IL byte array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray(v=vs.110).aspx)) using whatever kind of hash you want (e.g. SHA-256).

Of course, it's possible for the IL to change without the source code changing (e.g. due to changing compiler) - or vice versa (e.g. if a local variable name was changed but not present in the optimized IL).

Comment: You are a legend! Super fast and clear answers.  I think that for this purpose it is the IL that counts.  If it occasionally changes when it shouldn't have then that is fine - as long as it doesn't change on every compile. Time for some prototyping ...

Comment: I've edited the question with an implementation based on your answer.  It doesn't quite work for every kind of code change I'd like to detect however.  If you have time would you take a look please? Cheers, Rob

Comment: Another edit as I must have miss read my first attempt's results and LinqPad has a useful facility for easily checking the IL.  Next up would be to follow dependencies but at this point I'm beginning to think that a manually updated version attribute would be simpler even if it does rely on the programmer remembering to update it. Perhaps using Roslyn I could inject the hash into an attribute based on the [AST](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/11/03/using-the-roslyn-syntax-api.aspx) (food for thought!).

Comment: @WooWaaBob: So with your edit, it looks like it's okay as-is?

Comment: Yes thanks Jon. The current implementation looks like it is working for the basic scenarios listed there.  This would do as a first blush but I think I'd like to see how far it can be taken by following dependencies and therefore generating an overall hash. Cheers, Rob